# Need help installing python dependencies using pip

Tags: python, pip

My situation: I need to have same dependencies that I have on my computer on another server.

So I did this on my computer:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Than on a remote server:

I want to install requirements from the `requirements.txt` OS wide. How can I do this?

Comment: Read about virtualenv

Comment: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-freeze

Answer (score 1):

move the file over to your remote server and execute

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I did this, but the problem is modules are still not available

Comment: @Vor you really need to provide more information in your question in order to get help. Did you know what modules are missing? If yes then are they listed in your requirements.txt?